# Como puedo seleccionar departamento y que me traiga todos los municipios de ese departamento

Tags: android, volley

**ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO DE LA PRUEBA  MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA**

**json departamento prueba get**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id_departamento": 91,
            "departamento": "AMAZONAS"
        }
```

**json municipio PRUEBA GET**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id_municipio": "2",
            "municipio": "Acacías",
            "estado": "1",
            "departamento_id": "50",
            "departamento": {
                "id_departamento": 50,
                "departamento": "META"
            }
        }
```

**Este es el codigo que tengo para seleccionar DEPARTAMENTO y segun el departamento me traiga dinamicamente los municipios**

**Hata ahora solo me llena los spinner pero no consigo seleccionar DEPARTAMENTO Y QUE ME SALGAN LOS MUNICIPIOS DEL DEPARTAMENTO, SI ALQUIEN ME PUEDE COLABORAR LE AGRADEZCO.**

**cOMBO DEPARTAMENTO **

```
        comboDepartamento.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String sucursal = comboDepartamento.getSelectedItem().toString();
                for(int i=0;i<iddepartamento.size();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<departamento.size();j++){
                        if(sucursal == departamento.get(i)){
                            String id_del_departamento = iddepartamento.get(i);
                            listarMunicipios(id_del_departamento);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**COMBO MUNICIPIO**

```
comboMunicipios.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String municipios = comboMunicipios.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Snackbar.make(view,"Municipio seleccionado: "+municipios,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), municipios, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

**CONSUMIR DEPARTAMENTOS SPINNER**

```
   public void listarDepartamento() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String URL = ("http://actasentrega.colombia.org/api/departamentos/listado");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = jsonObject1.getString("id_departamento");
                        String country = jsonObject1.getString("departamento");
                        iddepartamento.add(id);
                        departamento.add(country);
                    }
                    comboDepartamento.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, departamento));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

**CONSUMIR MUNICIPIOS SPINNER**

```
 public void listarMunicipios(String id_del_departamento) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String URL = ("http://actasentrega.**texto en negrita**colombia.org/api/municipios/listado"+id_del_departamento);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String idmuni = jsonObject1.getString("id_municipio");
                        String muni = jsonObject1.getString("municipio");
                        idmunicipio.add(idmuni);
                        municipio.add(muni);
                    }
                    comboMunicipios.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, municipio));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hola. Estuve consultando un poco y noté que debes crear referencias al [API socrata](https://dev.socrata.com/) No contamos aún con la etiqueta [tag:socrata], y esto tal vez sea indicador de que aún no hay experticia en el tema

Comment: Muchas gracias.